# What am I? A rebus

Tags: rebus

What does the following rebus represent?

> Supenlla

Comment: @Gamow Thanks for the edit. What was I doing wrong that was making the question unacceptable?

Comment: Richard: I do not know. (Perhaps posting has a lower bound on length, but editing is unrestricted.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd imagine it's

> Su**pen**lla
>  "pen" in "Sulla"
>  Peninsula (misspelled as peninsulla)

Comment: Yep! I didn't misspell it though. I said "sulla" instead of "sula" because "sulla" is a reald word.

Comment: @RichardRoe: I think he means that "peninsulla" is misspelled.

Comment: And there I go. I make a post defending my spelling and I misspell a word in it!

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too much time on this one, overthinking it mostly.
 But it has to be

> Peninsula

because

> pen is in su"pen"lla, but if you take it out it's sulla, so pen is in sulla, pen-in-sulla, peninsulla, and it was just misspelled to lead people off track, so peninsula.